# Have/get it done vs. be done with it

Tags: phrase-usage

To me, the following sentences seem to mean the same thing, but my gut feeling tells me there *may* be some fine nuances in their usage, and native English speakers can easily appreciate them. An ESL learner, I can't do it.

Could anybody help me?

> They are expected to have it done by 3 pm tomorrow.
>
> They are expected to get it done by 3 pm tomorrow.
>
> They are expected to be done with it by 3 pm tomorrow.

Comment: Note: The third sentence has been edited - "get done with", as obviously bad grammar, was replaced with "be done with".

Answer (score 2):

1. To have something done by some time. = to finish it

They are expected to have it done by [by some agent] 3 pm tomorrow.

**Bear in mind**: "have it done" **can** be passive. It can imply you are having someone do it:

- I expected to have the house painted [by the painter] by Sunday.
- I expected to have the house painted by Sunday. [by me, to have the painting finished]. The context rules here.

The word **agent** is the word used to express who is doing something in a passive sentence.

2. They are expected to get it done by 3 pm tomorrow.

Basically, what was said for 1) applies here. "get something done" or "have something done" mean the same thing. To finish.

3. They are expected to get done with it by 3 pm tomorrow.

This one is **not quite** idiomatic. I would say:
They are expected **to be done with** it by 3 pm tomorrow.

the idiom here is: **to be done with something**, which means to be finished with something, but not to "finish something".

If something is **a burden on you**, if you say "I'm done with it". that means no longer want to have anything to do with it.

Often, used with people: After what he did to me, I'm done with him.

I'm done with house painting. Next time, I'll hire professionals to do the job for me.

To *get done with something* might be said but it is not quite idiomatic.

[I left the explanation for **get done with it**. Too much trouble to go back and edit.]